# CreateChildControls called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, composite-controls

I have a composite server control, where I implement CreateChildControls.
This control is a grid, which also includes paging and sorting controls.

When a sort link is clicked, CreateChildControls is called first, then the event handler and from the event handler I call CreateChildControls again, in order to rebuild the controls with the new sort order.

Is there any way to skip CreateChildControls when the postback was triggered by a control event handler?

Is this even possible or do I have to go through CreateChildControls before the event handler, so asp.net can hook up the event to an existing control?

Comment: It's normal to call CreateChildControls first so that event handlers can be hooked up.  Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: I do some heavy reflection, and I'm not pre-optimizing, but if I'm calling `CreateChildControls` once too many, it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know it at the time I wrote this question, but this is actually a part of the natural life cycle of a custom control.

`CreateChildControls()` is called each time `EnsureChildControls()` is called. The trick is to set the `ChildControlsCreated` property at the end of the first call to `CreateChildControls()`, so the entire process does not happen more than once.

Comment: EnsureChildControls (MSDN): `This method first checks the current value of the ChildControlsCreated property. If this value is false, the CreateChildControls method is called.` So you don't need any additional property to be sure that child controls already created

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy - That's what I said... If you override `CreateChildControls()` make sure to set `ChildControlsCreated`. That was the point.

Comment: so EnsureChildControls() does set ChildControlsCreated=true, but it looks like what Elad said makes sense, that way you would avoid the 1 call to ChildControlsCreated

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, but I have two things going on: I am loading controls, and then I am displaying information based on previous selections by the user. When a user changes a dropdownlist, or clicks a button, the page is reloaded and their choices are added to the querystring. So, my solution is this:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    AddControls();
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        return;
    ShowProcedure() // The time-intensive code that I don't want to call twice.
}
```

AddControls populates the controls, and enables the postback option. ShowProcedure uses the values from the querystring to show a lot of data. This way, I am not calling ShowProcedure on the CURRENT values.